# Is there a way in SQL to assign to a row the next value which is higher than itself?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to calculate query where a row in a new column takes on the next value which is higher than itself in a different column. I have tried using a rolling max method, but I have hit a wall because it involves specifying a specific number of rows to compare like so:

```
select t.*,
       max(val) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row) max3
from t;
```

Where we need to specify that the max will be calculated between the current row and 2 rows prior.

However, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
val        |   id    |   newcol       |
2          |  ABC    |   4            |
2          |  ABC    |   4            |
2          |  ABC    |   4            |
4          |  ABC    |   10           |
4          |  ABC    |   10           |
10         |  ABC    |   9999         |
10         |  ABC    |   9999         |
3          |  EFG    |   5            |
5          |  EFG    |   9            |
9          |  EFG    |   9999         |
2          |  HIJ    |   9999         |
7          |  KLM    |   11           |
11         |  KLM    |   12           |
12         |  KLM    |   9999         |
```

Where I partition by the id and the new col is assigned the next value in the val col which is higher than its own value (regardless of how many rows ahead it is) and assigns an arbitrary large number (9999) if it is already the highest value in its partition.

So far I have come up with this:

```
SELECT val, 
id,
CASE WHEN val = MAX(val) OVER(PARTITION BY id) THEN 9999 
ELSE MAX(val) OVER(partition by id ORDER BY val ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
END AS newcol
FROM table
ORDER BY ID;
```

However this just assigns the maximum value of the partition to any value which is not the maximum like this:

```
---------------------------------------
val        |   id    |   newcol       |
2          |  ABC    |   10           |
2          |  ABC    |   10           |
2          |  ABC    |   10           |
4          |  ABC    |   10           |
4          |  ABC    |   10           |
10         |  ABC    |   9999         |
10         |  ABC    |   9999         |
3          |  EFG    |   9            |
5          |  EFG    |   9            |
9          |  EFG    |   9999         |
2          |  HIJ    |   9999         |
7          |  KLM    |   11           |
11         |  KLM    |   11           |
12         |  KLM    |   9999         |
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a data sample? You only posted the desired output. Also what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need a range clause in order to look at distinct values. Order by value and get
the minimum value of all following (higher) values.

```
coalesce(min(val) over (partition by id
                        order by val
                        range between 1 following and unbounded following),
         9999) as newcol
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry but what is 'region_kz' in this case?

Comment: Oops, sorry, It is `val` of course. I was playing with a table of my own and forgot to change the column name in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I could:

```
with T as (
select *
from (values
 ('2022-01-01',2,'ABC',4)
,('2022-01-02',2,'ABC',4)
,('2022-01-03',2,'ABC',4)
,('2022-01-04',4,'ABC',10)
,('2022-01-05',4,'ABC',10)
,('2022-01-06',10,'ABC',9999)
,('2022-01-07',10,'ABC',9999)
,('2022-01-08',3,'EFG',5)
,('2022-01-09',5,'EFG',9)
,('2022-01-10',9,'EFG',9999)
,('2022-01-11',2,'HIJ',9999)
,('2022-01-12',7,'KLM',11)
,('2022-01-13',11,'KLM',12)
,('2022-01-14',12,'KLM',9999)
) T (Date, val, id, Expected)
),
 TDR as (
select
  t.*
  , DR=DENSE_RANK() over (partition by id order by val asc)
from t
)
select 
TDRT.*,
coalesce(TDRN.val,9999) as NextHigherVal
from 
    TDR as TDRT
    left join
    (select id, DR, val
     from TDR
     group by id, dr, val
     ) as TDRN
    on TDRT.id=TDRN.id
        and TDRT.DR+1=TDRN.DR
```

By no means the only solution.